# AWS glue cloud formation db creation error

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-cloudformation, aws-glue

I am trying to create a database on glue using cloud formation but it fails with the below error. Am I missing something?

```
Property validation failure: [The property {/DatabaseInput} is required, The property {/CatalogId} is required]
```

This is how my template code block looks like

```
GlueDatabase:
    Type: AWS::Glue::Database
    Properties: 
      CatalogId: !Ref AWS::AccountId 
      DatabaseInput: !Ref TeamName
```

Answer (score 1):

According to the [docs](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/aws-properties-glue-database-databaseinput.html) the `DatabaseInput` should have the following structure:

```
GlueDatabase:
    Type: AWS::Glue::Database
    Properties: 
      CatalogId: !Ref AWS::AccountId 
      DatabaseInput: 
        Description: String
        LocationUri: String
        Name: String
        Parameters: Json
```

Thus the question is, what `TeamName` is in your tempalte?